# onkeydown and onkeypressed on the same page

Tags: javascript

I have a JS file with both onkeydown and onkeypressed handler. However, after adding alert() in both handler, I can only see onkeypressed() being called. Why?

Comment: can you share your code snippet

Comment: this is probably because the alert interrupt the event, change to `console.log`

Comment: A really simple jsFiddle works in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/zLfjy/

Comment: can you share your code so people can understand clearly that what's your issues.

Comment: Both are called. testing in chrome